# Remove spaces when using Left function in the string of text

Tags: excel

I am using the following function `=UPPER(LEFT(G10,4))` but when a space occurs in the string of 4 how can I remove it?

So `G10` cell has the text: `Ab C defg` how can I get the result: `ABCD`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=UPPER(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(G10," ",""),4))
```

Comment: Thank you Ricardo.  I knew I had to use substitute but could not figure where to place it in the formula

Answer (score 2):

You can try `SUBSTITUTE`, this gets rid of your spaces, then to include it in the code you already have - it should look like this `=UPPER(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(G10," ",""),4))`.

Answer (score 1):

SUBSTITUTE function .  This can remove spaces by replacing them with nothing
=Substitute (A1, " ", "")

So use that inside your left()function